# Adding Multiple Recipients with Zend_Mail

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

With Zend_Mail (Zend v1.12), is there a way to configure the Zend_Mail object in order to send each recipient its own copy of the message?  It looks like the best answer is to use a foreach on an array of recipients, clearing the recipients on each iteration, and sending each time...

References:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.adding-recipients.html
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.multiple-emails.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zend_Mail::addBcc() and Zend_Mail::addCc() can take a single email or an array of emails.

```
addBcc(array(email@one.com, email@two.com));
addCc(array(email@one.com, email@two.com));
```

Comment: So using addBcc($recipients) is then equivalent to using a foreach that calls send()!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use array and the `foreach` loop to send.

Like that mail will be sent to all users separately.

```
$users = array("email1","email2","email3"); 
foreach ($users as $email) { 
   $mail->send() //part where you have send method 
}
```